# Java Selenium Gecko driver not loading

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, firefox

The ISSUE:

The geckodriver.exe is not loading when I run with testNG. Firefox will launch, but selenium cannot connect to the browser and I get an error:

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. ....
```

My setup:

- Windows 7
- Eclipse Neon 3
- Selenium 3.0.1
- Geckodriver v0.13.0 (was using v0.11.1)
- Firefox 48.0.2

First I created a quick test using Java and selenium. It just opens the browser and navigates to page. When this runs I see geckodriver process then the firefox process appear in the task manager.

Then I created a new project using Maven and testNG following the set-up from GURU99 web site. I have selenium and testNG added to the `pom.xml` file.

I used the convert project to testNG (xml file) and set the run configuration to run the XML file.

When I run the test I can see firefox process, then ff starts up. But the gecko driver process is never started.

Here is my code (excluding the imports):

```
public class NewTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void test01() {        
        driver.get("http://www.startpage.com");       
        System.out.println("Pge title " + driver.getTitle());                 
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");        
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed to set the Marionette capability, e.g.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", <<Your driver path here>>);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, true);
cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.BINARY, <<Your firefox.exe path here>>);
cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, <<Your firefox profile here>>);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

I am using the above and it works like charm!

For more, see: [Selenium 3 using Firefox Geckodriver](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1171895/Selenium-using-Firefox-Geckodriver).